# Alarm won't be raised when Cloudfront receives request

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cloudwatch-alarms

Below is my AWS Cloudwatch alarm syntax made with Terraform:

```hcl
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "service_start_alarm" {
  alarm_name                = "${var.module_name}-start"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  ok_actions                = []
  alarm_actions             = [var.trigger_sns.arn]
  treat_missing_data        = "notBreaching"
  metric_name               = "Requests"
  namespace                 = "AWS/CloudFront"
  statistic                 = "Sum"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = 1
  datapoints_to_alarm       = 1
  threshold                 = 0
  period                    = 60
  dimensions = {
    DistributionId = var.distribution_id
    Region         = "Global"
  }
}
```

I want to raise an alarm and trigger some execution logic when the Cloudfront distribution receives any request (The use-case is that the backend systems are down for a while, so the first request will trigger them)

However, when I entered the URL for the Cloudfront into my browser, **Cloudfront received 1 request, but there's NO alarm raised.**

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem regarding error code rate. I suppose your problem arises from the alarm being created in a region different than us-east-1. As CloudFront is a global service, alarms for CloudFront ought to be created in us-east-1. If this is indeed the case for your issue, I suggest defining an alternative AWS provider with `region="us-east-1"` and passing it explicitly in your alarm resource definition.

```hcl
provider "aws" {
    alias   = "useast1"
    region  = "us-east-1"
}
```

and then

```hcl
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm" {
    provider = aws.useast1
    #other alarm properties here
}
```

Comment: The documentation about CloudWatch alarm that needs to be deployed in us-east-1 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html

Answer (score 0):

If the metric represents the number of requests, a threshold of 0 might not be appropriate. Set threshold value that is more realistic based on your expected traffic. I would try 100

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "service_start_alarm" {
  alarm_name                = "${var.module_name}-start"
 ....................
  threshold                 = 100   *# Adjust this threshold based on expected traffic*
 ...........
  }
}
```

Moreover, make sure that metric "Requests" is named correctly in the "AWS/CloudFront" namespace.